# Unit Test or Mock: Testing Service Class in Spring Boot with Rest Template

Tags: spring-boot, rest, unit-testing, service, mocking

I have a service class, which for readability purpose, I have provided the code with dummy variables and objects. I am trying to write a JUNIT test class for the service, primarily with Mockito. No matter how hard I try, I am not able to hit the method serviceMethod irrespective of using spy/mock. I have also included the test I've written, following the main class.

The test passes without any errors, but is not able to call the method from the actual class. Henceforth, it is not being included in the test coverage. *(method in actual class is excluded in red on Eclipse/SONAR report)*

I know I am missing something here, but doesn't cross my mind. I need an eye to review this and let me know how I can write a proper test class for this and obtain coverage for the method.

(P.S. all the necessary imports are in-place and not pasted here to keep this concise)

Thanks in advance!

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@Service
public class ServiceClass {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ServiceClass.class);

    @Autowired
    private Config Config;

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public void serviceMethod(BusinessClass businessObject) {
        String NotificationUrl = Config.getApplicationProperty(businessObject.getCode()).getNotificationUrl();
        HttpEntity<StoreNotify> request = new HttpEntity<>(businessObject);
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(NotificationUrl, HttpMethod.POST, request,
                String.class);

        LOGGER.info("Service call, response: {} and status: {} ", response.getBody(),
                response.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

The Test Class for above,

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.times;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
public class ServiceClassTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceClass serviceClass;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private BusinessClass businessObject;

    @Test
    public void testServiceMethod() {

        ServiceClass spy = Mockito.spy(serviceClass);
        doNothing().when(spy).serviceMethod(businessObject);
        spy.serviceMethod(businessObject);
        verify(spy, times(1)).serviceMethod(businessObject);

        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(ArgumentMatchers.anyString(), ArgumentMatchers.any(HttpMethod.class),
                ArgumentMatchers.<HttpEntity<BusinessClass>>any(), ArgumentMatchers.<Class<String>>any()))
                .thenReturn(responseEntity);

    }

}
```

Comment: well since the actual method doesn't return anything. Mockito.doCallRealMethod() or Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS don't help either. @SupunWijerathne

Comment: @SupunWijerathne I guess that's where I'm falling short. What would be the best approach to test this class?

Comment: I would like to add a complete answer here. Just give me some time

Comment: Thank you @SupunWijerathne! I would be looking forward

Comment: what is the return type for Config.getApplicationProperty(businessObject.getCode()) ?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne the return type is say ConfigA

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code. You may need some changes if it is failing, just comment your result in case this below code does not work.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
public class ServiceClassTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceClass serviceClass;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Mock
    private Config Config;

    @Test
    public void testServiceMethod() { 

    BusinessClass businessObject = new BusinessClass();
    businessObject.setCode("123"); // set as per your datatype

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>("my String mock body", HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    Mockito.when(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(), Mockito.any()))
                .thenReturn(responseEntity);

    serviceClass.serviceMethod(businessObject);

    verify(serviceClass, times(1)).serviceMethod(Mockito.any(BusinessClass.class));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @SSK! I would try this and let you know how it goes

Comment: the serviceClass.serviceMethod(businessObject); is throwing a null pointer exception though all the fields under businessObject are set with values

Answer (score 0):

To start things simply, I would add the following test class which is indeed good enough for your situation.

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.http.HttpEntity;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceClassTest {
    private static final String CODE = "code";
    private static final String NOTIFICATION_URL = "notificationUrl";
    @Mock
    private Config config;
    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @InjectMocks
    private ServiceClass serviceClass;
    @Mock
    private BusinessClass businessObject;
    @Mock
    private Notification notification;

    @Test
    public void serviceMethod() {
        when(businessObject.getCode()).thenReturn(CODE);
        when(config.getApplicationProperty(CODE)).thenReturn(notification);
        when(notification.getNotificationUrl()).thenReturn(NOTIFICATION_URL);

        serviceClass.serviceMethod(businessObject);

        verify(restTemplate, times(1)).exchange(NOTIFICATION_URL, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(businessObject), String.class);
    }
}
```

If I'm providing a brief explanation of what this test method do

- First 3 lines: do necessary mocking to ensure that our test method only depends on the code inside `ServiceClass`. So in line#1: I make sure `businessObject.getCode()` returns the `CODE` I want. Note that `businessObject` is the parameter we are going to pass into `ServiceClass.serviceMethod(BusinessClass businessObject)` inside our test method. Now I know, whatever the case it is, `businessObject.getCode()` returns `CODE` so that inside my `ServiceClass.serviceMethod` (Original class) when I call `Config.getApplicationProperty(String code)`, `CODE` will pass as the parameter. Now in line#2: I advise whenever `CODE` is passed as the parameter for `config.getApplicationProperty(String code)` to return the `notification` I want. And in line#3: in turns, I advise to `notification.getNotificationUrl()` to return `NOTIFICATION_URL`.
- Call the method we want to test. Note that we should not be mocking this method.
- Since this is a void method, I'm using `Mockito.verify` to make sure that the execution happened inline with my mock arrangement and actual (original) class logic. Here what I'm verifying is the way that the executed code called the `restTemplate`.

As I mentioned at the beginning, what I wrote above is a simple test to cover your requirement. Once you digest that, you may have a look at [mock-server](https://www.mock-server.com/mock_server/getting_started.html), which might be helpful for you to carry out testing rest calls.

Comment: Thank you much @Supun. I've got the idea. While trying to incorporate that, I'm repeatedly facing the null pointer exception w.r.t serviceClass.serviceMethod(businessObject); Also, there is no such equivalent class for "Notification" as provided in the above sample. :)

Comment: @siriusblack I ran it and there were no NPE for me. In which line the NPE throws? And You can replace your class for 'Notification' class (Not a big issue)

Comment: serviceClass.serviceMethod(businessObject); throws NPE. Even if I create a new object of BusinessClass and set all the values, then pass it to serviceClass.serviceMethod()

Comment: I'm asking you the exact line which throws the exception not anything in call stack. I mean for serviceClass.serviceMethod(businessObject) line to throw NPE, the only reason can be serviceClass to be null (which can never happen). So, please just tell the exact line or can you just add the stack trace to your question please?

Comment: Here is the actual code, 
79: planitService.planitStoreNotification(store);
80: verify(restTemplate, times(1)).exchange(NOTIFICATION_URL, HttpMethod.POST, new HttpEntity<>(StoreNotify.class),
    String.class);

Stack trace,
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at xxx.xxxxx.xxx.service.PlanitService.planitStoreNotification(PlanitService.java:35)
 at xxx.xxxxx.xxx.service.PlanitServiceTest.testPlanitStoreNotification(PlanitServiceTest.java:79)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

Comment: what is this planitService? you haven't mentioned such in your question right?

Comment: planitService is the ServiceClass. I renamed for readability

Comment: @siriusblack then what is planitService.planitStoreNotification(store); ?? I think your code has been changed. So problem could be some other thing. The only way I can help is that if you post your new code